# Index() & match() function doesn't recognize duplicated values

Tags: excel, excel-match

Please check the below screenshot:
The issue is that the Match() function does not recognize duplicated values.
The H2 and J2 cells are not showing the desired result.

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VHIJ4.png)

Comment: will `max()` with `countif()` work?

Comment: I don't think so, Can you please explain more?
I am using excel 2016 as a beginner.

Comment: how does ur `max() `  function look like? [edit] the question to add those info (as per [recommended](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users))

Comment: Please show a screen shot of what you expect for results.

Comment: please check the revised question.

Comment: Show the image, or better yet, the data so we can test without typing useless info.

Comment: Probably one of your 25% values is not exactly 25% (it will be a floating point number formatted as a %). If you want to compare calculated numbers exactly it is best to round to the required precision before doing the lookup or compare.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, not sure what you want exactly, but I use this to get the Top 5 and it deals with duplicates:

[image]

Formula in B1:

```
=LARGE(B$13:B$30,ROW())
```

Formula in A1:

```
=INDEX(A$13:A30,AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW($1:$30)/(B$13:B$30=B1),COUNTIF(B$1:B1,B1)))
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, it was exactly what I needed.